# How can I get Spark/Shark to start on DSE 4.5.1

Tags: apache-spark, datastax-enterprise, shark-sql

This was initially working out of the box and then AWS kindly shut down this server for me.  So I rebuilt it and made it the new job tracker (it was also the old job tracker).  Now I can't figure out how to get Spark/Shark to run.  I get the same output with just typing `dse shark` as I do with adding the environment variables.  I'm not sure what's missing or where to set what variables to make them work.

```
root@shark-001:/var/log/cassandra# SPARK_MASTER_IP=10.63.145.204 SPARK_MASTER_ADDRESS=spark://10.63.145.204:7077 dse shark
Error when fetching Spark master address:
Starting the Shark Command Line Client
Logging initialized using configuration in /etc/dse/shark/log4j.properties
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: 'java.io.IOException: Spark not enabled on this node.
at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.getSparkMasterAddress(DseDaemon.java:228)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.getAttribute(PerInterface.java:83)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.getAttribute(MBeanSupport.java:206)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:647)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:678)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1464)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getAttribute(RMIConnectionImpl.java:657)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)'
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:1304)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:199)
at shark.SharkContext.<init>(SharkContext.scala:42)
at shark.SharkContext.<init>(SharkContext.scala:61)
at shark.SharkEnv$.initWithSharkContext(SharkEnv.scala:78)
at shark.SharkEnv$.init(SharkEnv.scala:38)
at shark.SharkCliDriver.<init>(SharkCliDriver.scala:284)
at shark.SharkCliDriver$.main(SharkCliDriver.scala:163)
at shark.SharkCliDriver.main(SharkCliDriver.scala)
```

**UPDATE:** Output from `dsetool status`:

```
root@shark-001:/var/log/cassandra# dsetool status
Note: Ownership information does not include topology, please specify a keyspace.
Address          DC           Rack         Workload         Status  State    Load             Owns                 Token
                                                                                                                   3326402795750538789
10.63.145.204    Analytics    rack1        Analytics(JT)    Up      Normal   199.58 MB        33.33%               -8971426586722495619
10.AA.BBB.CCC    Analytics    rack1        Analytics(TT)    Up      Normal   460.36 MB        33.33%               -2822511895485978416
10.XX.YYY.ZZZ    Analytics    rack1        Analytics(RT)    Up      Normal   272.4 MB         33.33%               3326402795750538789
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is the other files that were asked for: http://pastie.org/9527227

```
root@shark-001:/var/log/cassandra# dsetool sparkmaster
Error when fetching Spark master address:
java.io.IOException: Spark not enabled on this node.
at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.getSparkMasterAddress(DseDaemon.java:228)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.getAttribute(PerInterface.java:83)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.getAttribute(MBeanSupport.java:206)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:647)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:678)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1464)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getAttribute(RMIConnectionImpl.java:657)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
root@shark-001:/var/log/cassandra# grep SPARK /etc/default/dse
SPARK_ENABLED=1
```

**UPDATE 3:** system.log file is available here: http://pastebin.com/TaRYUSf4

Comment: Can you share your resources/spark/logs/master.log and resources/spark/conf/spark-env.sh/ ? Also, what does 'dsetool sparkmaster' return?

Comment: I take it you're starting DSE as a service hence SPARK_ENABLED=1 . Are there any errors in your system.log?

Answer (score 1):

I see this exact error when I try to start Shark or Spark against a Cassandra only node.

Can you share the output of `dsetool status` it should recognize the workload as Analytics.

If it shows Casandra workload, restart DSE using `dse cassandra -k`